# Internal Server Error 500 on Apache for perl script

Tags: apache, perl, internal-server-error, cgi-bin

I have a perl script in my cgi-bin. It first prints out the following statements

```
print "Status: 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";
```

It generates a html form on the terminal perfectly but when I try running it on the browser it gives the following error

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
>   contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them
>   of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just
>   before this error.

I have enabled cgi-bin in the apache configuration, the error log prints the following error

> End of script output before headers

What could be the problem and how should I resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Content-Type be the first thing printed back to the screen.  Also make sure the script is set as executable.

```
print "Status: 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";
```

Should be:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\nStatus: 200 OK\n";
```

Comment: I did that it didnt work, Status 200 is only to check if it generates a form on the terminal, the script is executable what do you think we should do?

Comment: I did, got the following error [cgid:error] End of script output before headers

Comment: The script same above is the full script, correct?  Do you have SSH access on your server?  If so try running the script in SSH (perl <script_name.pl>)

Comment: No it's not the full script it's too long and also generates a HTML output. I checked the form generated by copying and pasting the output into a HTML file after running the script from the terminal,  The html file works fine separately just not with apache. What do you think we should do about it?

Comment: For testing what I do is put print "test"; \_\_END\_\_ in my codes and keep going line by line until I find the offending line that is causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The script also needs to be executable by Apache for it to work

```
chmod a+x YourScript.pl
```

I've tested with the following script and once I fixed the permissions it works just fine. You also only need to set the status if it isn't 200 as that's the default.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
print "Status: 200\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";

print "<p>Foo</p>";
```

Comment: The script is executable and is giving the same error, what do you think we should do?

Comment: Could you try the script I provided above and see if that works?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your code then. Given you're not getting any other errors in the log, the likely problem is your script isn't outputting anything, not even the headers.